# Repeat function for Tiff file needed TILE function

Tags: c#, imaging

I want to read image file (6477 X 6840) pixels and copy it 2 time in Y and 8 times in X.
I have tried so many procedures but time consumption is too high.

```
public static void FillPattern(Graphics g, Image image, Rectangle rect) 
{ 
    Rectangle imageRect; 
    Rectangle drawRect; 
    for (int x = rect.X; x < rect.Right; x += image.Width) 
    { 
        for (int y = rect.Y; y < rect.Bottom; y += image.Height) 
        { 
            drawRect = new Rectangle(x, y, Math.Min(image.Width, rect.Right - x), 
                Math.Min(image.Height, rect.Bottom - y)); 
            imageRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, drawRect.Width, drawRect.Height); 
            g.DrawImage(image, drawRect, imageRect, GraphicsUnit.Pixel); 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: its simple code but took almost 15 minute for 1000x1000 pixel file.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Can you imagine the amount of pixels your app has to render? Even opening of such a file with the Paint or Photoshop might be an issue for a weak PC.

Comment: @BorisSokolov this is for printing application file. & printing size will be around 1208mmX3200mm with 720 dpi resolution, we are currently achieving with 2 stages, Ripping & printing. i want to design a software which can directly print it.

Comment: Hm... in this case I would rather go with some kind of specialized software (kind of Photoshop, etc.) I don't believe it is realistic to achieve reasonable performance with Graphics library

Answer (score 0):

```
 if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            foreach (String file in openFileDialog1.FileNames)
            {
                using (MagickImage image = new MagickImage(file))
                {
                    image.Format = MagickFormat.Tiff;
                    EnteredRepeat = short.Parse(TxbLenRpt.Text);
                    for (int i = 0; i < EnteredRepeat; i++)
                    {
                        image.Write("D:\\IMAGICK\\Apped Folder\\Outfile" + i+".tiff");
                    }
                    using (MagickImageCollection frames = new MagickImageCollection())
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < EnteredRepeat; i++)
                        {
                            string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"D:\\IMAGICK\\Apped Folder", "*.tiff");
                            frames.Add(files[i]);
                            frames.AppendHorizontally();
                            frames.Write("D:\\IMAGICK\\MultiRepeat.tiff");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

> I found this way of creating multiple files from file & then appending them in horizontal to achive subjected solution.
> Code works fine without any error. It creates EnteredRepeat nos of files also. But while appened it give only one single file with original filesize.
> Just trying hard since 3 days & stuck at last moment.
> seeking your hels friend.